# How to fit long text into UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want the title in the navigation bar to automatically shrink so it can fit the entire title. I tried the following code, but the title is still cut off.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    titleLabel.text = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if ([titleLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setMinimumScaleFactor:)]) {
        titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1;
    } else {
        titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 1.0;
    }
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

[image]

Comment: the doc of `UINavigationItem` says about the `titleView` property: *If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title. This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil.*. Is that the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the label that it should try to automatically adjust the fine:

```
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```